# How do you make separate curves for test and training in TensorBoard like in the interactive demo?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I was looking at [the interactive demo in tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/index.html#events) and it seems that they have separate test and training plots that one can toggle. For example they have separate accuracies for for test and train:

[image]

and one can toggle between them:

[image]

they even have separate percentile (hist) graphs too:

[image]

what is the TensorFlow code that provides such a useful functionality?

---

I tried having both test and train error but I don't get plots like that. This is what I tried:

```
with open(path+errors_pretty, 'w+') as f_err_msgs:
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        merged = tf.merge_all_summaries()
        writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter(tensorboard_data_dump, sess.graph)

        sess.run( tf.initialize_all_variables() )
        for i in xrange(steps):
            ## Create fake data for y = W.x + b where W = 2, b = 0
            #(batch_xs, batch_ys) = get_batch_feed(X_train, Y_train, M, phase_train)
            feed_dict_batch = get_batch_feed(X_train, Y_train, M, phase_train)
            ## Train
            if i%report_error_freq == 0:
                (summary_str_train,train_error) = sess.run(fetches=[merged, l2_loss], feed_dict=feed_dict_train)
                (summary_str_test,test_error) = sess.run(fetches=[merged, l2_loss], feed_dict=feed_dict_test)
                writer.add_summary(summary_str_train, i)

                loss_msg = "Model *%s%s*, step %d/%d, training error %g, test error %g \n"%(model,nb_hidden_layers,i,steps,train_error,test_error)
                mdl_info_msg = "Opt: %s, BN %s, After %d/%d iteration, Init: %s \n" % (optimization_alg,bn,i,steps,init_type)
                print_messages(loss_msg, mdl_info_msg)
                # store results
                results['train_errors'].append(train_error)
                results['test_errors'].append(test_error)
                # write errors to pretty print
                f_err_msgs.write(loss_msg)
                f_err_msgs.write(mdl_info_msg)
                # save mdl
                #save_path = saver.save(sess, path+'/tmp_mdls/model.ckpt',global_step=i)
                if mdl_save:
                    save_path = saver.save(sess, path+mdl_dir+'/model.ckpt',global_step=i)
            sess.run(fetches=[merged,train_step], feed_dict=feed_dict_batch)
            #sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})
```

Answer (score 4):

Tensor board makes use of the log folder structure, to organise the front end. To get two separate accuracies have two separate summary writers in two folders like below

```
     with open(path+errors_pretty, 'w+') as f_err_msgs:
with tf.Session() as sess:
    merged = tf.merge_all_summaries()
    ***train_writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter(tensorboard_train_data_dump, sess.graph)***
     ***test_writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter(tensboar_test_data_sump, sess.graph)***

    sess.run( tf.initialize_all_variables() )
    for i in xrange(steps):
        ## Create fake data for y = W.x + b where W = 2, b = 0
        #(batch_xs, batch_ys) = get_batch_feed(X_train, Y_train, M, phase_train)
        feed_dict_batch = get_batch_feed(X_train, Y_train, M, phase_train)
        ## Train
        if i%report_error_freq == 0:
            (summary_str_train,train_error) = sess.run(fetches=[merged, l2_loss], feed_dict=feed_dict_train)
            (summary_str_test,test_error) = sess.run(fetches=[merged, l2_loss], feed_dict=feed_dict_test)
            ***train_writer.add_summary(summary_str_train, i)
            test_writer.add_summary(summary_str_test, i)***

            loss_msg = "Model *%s%s*, step %d/%d, training error %g, test error %g \n"%(model,nb_hidden_layers,i,steps,train_error,test_error)
            mdl_info_msg = "Opt: %s, BN %s, After %d/%d iteration, Init: %s \n" % (optimization_alg,bn,i,steps,init_type)
            print_messages(loss_msg, mdl_info_msg)
            # store results
            results['train_errors'].append(train_error)
            results['test_errors'].append(test_error)
            # write errors to pretty print
            f_err_msgs.write(loss_msg)
            f_err_msgs.write(mdl_info_msg)
            # save mdl
            #save_path = saver.save(sess, path+'/tmp_mdls/model.ckpt',global_step=i)
            if mdl_save:
                save_path = saver.save(sess, path+mdl_dir+'/model.ckpt',global_step=i)
        sess.run(fetches=[merged,train_step], feed_dict=feed_dict_batch)
        #sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})
```

Although this is a little bit messy, this is a work around that will give you 2 "runs". I have done this myself as you can see in the image below. The purple line corresponds to training accuracy at different epochs and the brown line corresponds to validation accuracy at different epochs. Hope this helps you :)

[image: Train and test accuracy]

Comment: right now I have two `sess.run()` one for test and one for train and they both give summary strings. Do I just pass the corresponding strings to the corresponding writer? I updated my question with a small clip of code so that you can sort of see what I am doing. Do you mind maybe providing some more code to see how a working example works? Its unclear to me how to sue the writers correctly.

Comment: @Pinocchio Based on the code that you have given, I have updated the answer to reflect this. The changes in the code that I have made is marked with ***.

Comment: maybe can you provide the code that you wrote that provides the plot on your answer? I made the changes you suggested but now I have two folders with the data for tensorboard called `tensorboard_train_data_dump` and `tensorboard_test_data_dump`. Now I am running one 'tensorboard --logdir=/tmp/mdl_logs_train' but I can only see the results for 1 of my runs instead of both of them in one screen. How do you tell tensorboard that I have two runs and that it should combine them in the browser?

Comment: Oops sorry.. My code is in a private repo as of now :) Wish I could provide it.. Nonetheless I can provide you with the answer. If your folder structures is 

`logs/tensorboard_train_data_dump` 

 `logs/tensor board_test_data_dump` 

Then run `tensorboard.py --logdir=logs`. This makes sure that the test and train are in the same tensorboard

Comment: @Pinocchio I have made the code available here https://github.com/abhinavkashyap92/tensor-flow-neural-nets